# How to differentiate a value's data type by using typeof in JS especially for null and actual object?

Tags: javascript, object, null, compare, typeof

I came across a situation where I'm not able to solve it, maybe it's easy for someone.

API response [{a: null, b: 'example'}, {a: {c: 'example'}, b: 'example'}]

How to differentiate the 'a' field based on its datatype by using typeof, since it returns 'object' for both null & {c: 'example'}.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ?? operator instead of typeof operator